# storing the contents or a for loop into an array and then retrieving it for if statements

Tags: bash

I'm having a bit of trouble, id like to store the contents of the values from my for loop into an array or something and then recall these values to be tested against the if statements and then printed accordingly. My current code gives me a good output however if I use large numbers like 1 and 50 as input values it gives me multiple rows of "Divisible by xValue" instead of just one of each value. Thanks in advance

```
if (( $# > 2 )); then
        echo "Only your first two values will be used"
        for((i=($1+($1%2));i<($2-3);i+=2));do  #for loop lists all even numbers between two input values

        if (( i %  7 == 0 )); then #checks if even number divisible by 7
                echo " $i : Divisible by 7 " # prints number and labels 
                elif (( $i % 11 == 0 )); then #else if checks if divisible by 7
                        echo " $i : Divisible by 11 " #prints number and labels 
                        elif (( $i % 13 == 0 )); then  #if divisible by 13
                                echo " $i : Divisible by 13 "  
                        fi   #closes the if statement
                        printf "%d%s, " "$i"
                        done
        echo "$i"
```

Comment: What numbers do you want to get in the array?

Comment: I think there's a missing `fi` before line 3 of the script.

Comment: numbers going into the array would be even numbers. The user inputs two values, the for loop then calculated even numbers between the two input values. I would like the even numbers that have been calculated by the for loop to be stored into an array and then the if and life statements to be used on these numbers from the array after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+=()` in bash to add a new element into an array.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu

if (( $# > 2 )); then
    echo "Only your first two values will be used"
fi

even=()
for ((i=$1; i<=$2; ++i)) ; do
    if (( i % 2 == 0 )) ; then
        even+=($i)
    fi
done

for e in "${even[@]}" ; do
    for d in 7 11 13 ; do
        if (( e %  d == 0 )); then
            echo "$e: Divisible by $d"
            break
        fi
    done
    printf "%d%s, " "$e"
done
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much, would you be able to explain how the array works in bash? id love to learn it for next time I do something.

Comment: Search `man bash` for all mentions of "array" to learn about arrays in bash. If you have specific questions, ask them here (as new questions, not as comments).